# concatenation of triple quoted strings

Tags: python, syntax-error, concatenation, string-interpolation

I am currently trying to concatenate within a triple-quoted string using variables.  What is the best way to go about this?

```
print('''
Points left to spend: ''' + str(pointsLeft) + '''
''' + str(attrChoice) + ':\t' + '''[''' + str(charAttr[attrChoice]) + ''']
To reduce the number of points spent on this skill, simply enter a negative number.
'''
)
```

The error message I got was: keyword can't be an expression.  Could anyone explain what this means and if it is at all possible to attempt such a concatenation?

Comment: what are `attrChoice`, `charAttr` etc..?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The best way to do that is with [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
template = """This is a 
multiline {0} with
replacement {1} in."""

print(template.format("string", "fields"))
```

---

From Python 3.6 (see [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)) you can do this using an "f-string" as follows:

```
print(f'''
Points left to spend: {pointsLeft}
{attrChoice}:\t[{charAttr[attrChoice]}]
To reduce the number of points spent on this skill, simply enter a negative number.
'''
)
```

Comment: Thanks.  That should be effective.  i would mark you up, but lack the reputation.

Comment: How would you achieve this with multiple replacements within the same string?

Comment: @PedroRhian What do you mean? My example has multiple replacements.

Comment: I find this solution to be especially useful when creating HTML or XML documents.